# Photoshop clear makes adjacent pixels semi transparent

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I make a selection of some pixels and press *delete*, Photoshop does get rid of the pixels but as well makes the adjacent pixels (which were not selected) semi transparent for some reason. I would like to delete precisely the selected area.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you set "feather" (in options block above the canvas) to something other than zero.

Check the screenshot at http://designshack.net/articles/software/8-ways-to-get-the-selection-you-want-in-photoshop/ under paragraph "Additional options" near the top to see what I mean.

Comment: I have set it to 0 and still same problem.